# Accessing dictionary W/ Nested loops - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
dic = {"Vegetables":["Carrots","Broccoli","Mushrooms"], "fruits":["Apples ","Citrus"]}
for itm in dic: 
    for val in dic.values():
        print("{} are {}".format(dic[itm][val]))
```

How would I print ex.

```
Carrots are Vegetables
Apples are fruits
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `items()` method of dict. It will let you iterate over its keys and values.

So each key will be a string, and each value a list - you do not need to call any methods besides `items()` in your code, and you do not need to use `[]` anywhere.

```py
for key, value in dic.items():
    for item in value:
        print(f'{item} are {key}')
```

A tip since you are clearly a Python beginner: Iterating over dict keys only (`for key in somedict`) is something you rarely do in Python - especially if the first thing inside that loop is something like `value = somedict[key]`; as you see in my example above, `items()` is much nicer since it will give you both at the same time.

Comment: Exactly what OP asked for, good answer

Answer (score 1):

The first loop should iterate through the keys, while the second loop goes through the corresponding values. As it stands now, your loops are disconnected.

```
dic = {"Vegetables": ["Carrots", "Broccoli", "Mushrooms"], "fruits": ["Apples ", "Citrus"]}
for itm in dic:  # iterate through keys
    for val in dic[itm]:  # iterate through list corresponding to the key
        print("{} are {}".format(val, itm))  # print
```

Result:

```
Carrots are Vegetables
Broccoli are Vegetables
Mushrooms are Vegetables
Apples  are fruits
Citrus are fruits
```

Comment: While not wrong, the more pythonic approach is to use `for key, value in dict.items`

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp OP should know why their code is not working not just what the better way is.

Comment: My guess would be because while it fixes the code of what's clearly a beginner, it not tell them that there is a much better way of doing this (and why).

Comment: @ThiefMaster yours (and others) answers have already done that.

Comment: @ThiefMaster with all respect, the question is not "The best way" or "Pythonic way". It asks how the job can be done. And unlike most of other users, it explains why the code would work.

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```py
for key, values in dic.items():
    for val in values:
        print('{val} are in {key}'.format(val=val, key=key))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.items()`.

```py
dic = {"Vegetables":["Carrots","Broccoli","Mushrooms"], "fruits":["Apples ","Citrus"]}

for category, things in dic.items():
    for thing in things:
        print(f"{thing} are {category}")
```

Output:

```py
Carrots are Vegetables
Broccoli are Vegetables
Mushrooms are Vegetables
Apples  are fruits
Citrus are fruits
```

Comment: `s/list/things/`? :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Haha good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
dic = {"Vegetables":["Carrots","Broccoli","Mushrooms"], "fruits":["Apples ","Citrus"]}
for key, value in dic.items():
    print(f'key is {key}, value is {value}')

key is Vegetables, value is ['Carrots', 'Broccoli', 'Mushrooms']
key is fruits, value is ['Apples ', 'Citrus']
```